# VBA way to select files and then destination folder

Tags: vba, powerpoint, filepicker

I am trying to select a bunch of files, using:

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

and then I have to process each one of the selected files (I allow multiple selection) and write it back into a destination directory.
My problen is that when I use:

```
Set destFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

to pick the destination folder, `fd` gets overwritten, because the Application object only can instantiate a single `FileDialog` object. And then I loose the `SelectedItems` list from `fd`.

How should I do it so I can keep the list for iteration?

Comment: Please join your code, that will be easier for us to help you. you might be able to store both the folder `fd` and the `SelectItems` in variables and if you have a lot of them, store them into an array (1 column for the folder path (as string) and 1 for the selected items) that you'll process when the array is filled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the SelectedItems list returned by fd.

```
Sub test()
    Dim fd As FileDialog, destFolder As FileDialog
    Dim s As FileDialogSelectedItems
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Show
    Set s = fd.SelectedItems ' s will be kept after next line
    Set destFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
End Sub
```